# Perl Term::Screen Enable insert character / delete character

Tags: perl

The Perl module [Term::Screen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Screen) has a method for inserting a character and deleting a character.  Both of these methods have an accompanying method to check if the interface allows for such actions [ic_exists() and dc_exists()].  I'm running this script through a ssh session and the ic_exists and dc_exists are returning 0, not available.  What do I need to do to enable the insert character and delete character for this module?

Comment: Are you doing `ssh somewhere` and then running the script from the shell, or are you doing `ssh somewhere /path/to/script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `TERM` in your ssh environment is set to something that supports those functions (and is compatible with your terminal).

Try adding

```
print "$ENV{TERM}\n";
```

to your script to see what terminal it thinks it's talking to.