# Perl Term::Screen Enable insert character / delete character (2)

Tags: perl

I see this post but doesn't help me.
[Perl Term::Screen Enable insert character / delete character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429095/perl-termscreen-enable-insert-character-delete-character)

```
print "$ENV{TERM}\n";
```

returns xterm

Q1) How to delete/insert characters with this module?

> The readline() function does always return on the following keys:
>   Enter, Arrow Up, Arrow Down, Esc, Tab and Ctrl-Enter/F4.

SRC: [Note of ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/~oesterhol/Term-Screen-ReadLine-0.37/ReadLine.pm#readline%28%29)

Q2) How to replace this behavior to return when q is pressed?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the 'delete key' has changed from 8 to 127 over the
>   years.
>   src: Hans Oesterholt

The new version v0.38 manage backspace.